# Using Fragments before they are attached

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a master/detail type application. The Master view is a MasterFragment that shows a list of Master items, while the Detail view is a DetailsFragment that shows a list of Detail items.

When a user clicks a Master item in the list, I create a new DetailsFragment and show it using a transaction.

The details shown in a DetailFragment take some time to load (seconds) so I want to load them in a background thread and show the list once the loading is finished.

I now want to give the user the option to long-click a Master item, which (instead of opening it immediately and letting him wait) will create the DetailsFragment in the background (not visible yet), allowing him to browse the MasterFragment while it's loading. A navigation item is added to the Navigation Drawer so he can navigate to the DetailsFragment after some time when it has finished loading.

Think of it like using a web browser on very slow internet - instead of opening a page and waiting for it to load it is much nicer to open a page in a new tab in the background, browsing the current page some more while it loads, and then going back to the new tab when you think it must be finished loading. That's what I want to do in my app as well except with Fragments.

Now I learned that with creating Fragments it's important to use a static factory method that creates the Fragment, adds any objects as arguments to a Bundle, and then leave only an empty constructor.

```
public class DetailsFragment : Fragment
{
    public DetailsFragment()
    {
        // Leave empty
    }

    public static DetailsFragment create(int masterId)
    {
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("MasterId", masterId);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    private void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        // Get master ID
        int masterId = getArguments().getInt("MasterId");

        // Load details in background thread
        load(masterId);
    }

    @Background
    private void load(int masterId)
    {
        //... (loading takes a few seconds...)
        loadFinished();
    }

    @UiThread
    private void loadFinished()
    {
        // update view...
    }
}
```

(Note: I am using Android Annotations so that the 'load' method (with the @Background annotation) is run in the background. Just pretend I start it using a runner or AsyncTask or whatever.)

There is a problem here however: onCreate is not called until the Fragment is 'called upon', in other words there is no loading being done until the user opens the details fragment. I have tried onAttach instead of onCreate but the same thing happens. It seems onAttach is the first method called in the lifecycle and that is already too late.

I want the loading to start immediately, even if the Fragment is not shown yet (it may never be shown if the user doesn't navigate to it anymore).

How can I implement this behavior?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Comment: I reverted to showing the fragment (adding it to the stack) and immediately hiding it again. It worked, but it was such a mess that I completely abandoned the idea altogether soon after.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I preload a fragment.  Not sure it is the best way or the android way but it's the way I figured out how to do it.

In my layout xml I have the following:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/master_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Notice that the "details_frame" is invisible.  Then when you want to preload the fragment , you replace the invisible details_frame with the fragment and it will remain invisible:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.details_frame, <DetailsFragment>, <FragmentName>)
            .commit();
```

Then once you want to display it you change the visibility to visible instead of invisible.

```
findViewById(R.id.details_frame).setVisibilility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that will work for me... The user can have multiple Detail fragments "open" at the same time (meaning: in the background, only one can be visible at once). When he preloads a fragment I add an item to a navigation drawer which he can use to navigate to that fragment later. There may be many fragments such as this all at the same time in the navigation drawer and he should be able to switch back and forth between them. This means the frame that contains the fragment must be visible because the user could be using a different Detail fragment while another is loading.

Comment: Maybe try dynamically creating the FrameLayouts with their IDs and see if that will work.  I'm not sure how the transaction manager works with dynamically created views as I haven't played with that.